# Joomla 3 template pages load very slowly

Tags: mysql, css, joomla3.0

I am experimenting with a Joomla 3 site using - http://crosstec.de/templatedemos11/ - template - this is my introduction to Joomla.

My Joomla development site is - http://clickandrent.mobi - runs very slow takes about 20sec to load a page, I have only got a 20 articles in the database and only 5 of them are active.

There are 3 active links on the bottom menu - "Terms", "Privacy Policy" and "Contact" - and the "Home" link is active on the top menu.

I enabled the cache in the global settings and tried the *GZip* option to compress up the CSS - I also switched on *Debug* - and started to look at Firebug, and noticed a few MySQL SELECT statements in the debug output of the Joomla that show "no index" but I am not sure if they are causing the load speed issues, but being a newbie to this it has me stumped.

My other development site, a standard php based site - http://clickworldwide.com/en/index.php - runs really quick so I assume that the development server is okay.

Comment: Crosstec demo loads in 5.47 seconds so something is wrong with your server.

Comment: Not a good comparison as we do not know the size and power of the Crosstec Server - my other code heavy php development sites run really quick on the dev server

Comment: While that's not the root cause of your problem note that the page is extremely heavy. All requests sum up to 4.8 MB. For slow connections this is way too much.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - I started to try and understand the workings of FireBug - even with the "About Us" link at the bottom, this is a blank html Article it still takes 12-13secs to load a page with nothing in it. It looks like an issue with the template design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was that the {webroot}/cache/gantry folders was not writeable so the cache was not working.

Goes like the wind now.